# Given a distribution find the probability.

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 4 elevators. So far...

Elevator 1 opened 45.455% of the time (5/11).
Elevator 2 opened 27.273% of the time (3/11).
Elevator 3 opened 18.182% of the time (2/11).
Elevator 4 opened 9.091% of the time (1/11).

Given this information, what is the probability of getting each elevator the next time you're waiting for one. Assume that the elevators are independent of each other.

The goal is to guess, accurately as possible, which elevator door will open the next time.

Comment: assuming elevators are not independent? What's 11? Are you estimating the probability distribution? distribution is probability. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: You don't know anything about the probability distribution for sure, just that all elevators have a positive chance of opening. What is the point of your question?

Comment: @Memming `11` is the total number of elevator rides. Essentially I want to guess which elevator door will open the next time. So, I just want to figure out the probability before guessing.

Comment: You need to assume something more to do good inference here. And considering your small sample size, you'll likely end up with large error bars. Is this a real problem?

Comment: @Memming What other assumptions are required? Yes, this is a real problem but it's just something I'm doing for fun.

Comment: @icanc you are estimating a distribution from observations. E.g, if you assume independent observation, and a Dirichlet prior on probabilities, you could estimate the probabilities better.

Comment: In an important sense, the elevators cannot be independent of each other: if one opens first then the others do not.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

1)  Your lifts could be appearing with equal probability and you are just seeing this pattern because of your small sample.  It slightly depends on how you measure distance from what might be expected

If you take a sum of squares approach, I think you may find that the probability of getting as extreme an observation as you did or a more extreme one is about $44.3\%$ so you cannot reasonably reject such a hypothesis of equal probability.

2) You could try to use Bayesian methods and start off thinking that certain elevators may be more likely than others, but you do not know which or by how much.  First you need a prior distribution for the probabilities of the different elevators arriving (constrained so the probabilities add up to $1$ which makes this less than easy).  Then you need to combine these with the likelihood of seeing what you observed to give a posterior distribution.

If you assuming all combinations of probabilities summing to $1$ are equally likely, then I think you will find a $95\%$ central credible interval for the first elevator's posterior probability is between about $18\%$ and $65\%$, for the second elevator's probability is between about $8\%$ and $51\%$,  for the third elevator's probability is between about $5\%$ and $43\%$,  and for the fourth elevator's probability is between about $2\%$ and $34\%$.

With this prior, the posterior means for the elevator probabilities are $\frac{6}{15}, \frac{4}{15}, \frac{3}{15}, \frac{2}{15}$ respectively, i.e. about $40\%, 27\%, 20\%, 13\%$, but given the wide range of uncertainty resulting from your small sample, this does not tell you much.  [It is not a coincidence that $6=5+1, $ $4=3+1, $ $3=2+1,$ and $ 2=1+1$.]

Whichever approach you take, the conclusion is really that your observation size is too small to draw a helpful conclusion.

Some of the results above are empirical, but I expect them to be reasonably accurate.